# Angular 5: after 'ng build', how does the browser understand what <app-root> is?

Tags: angular

I have just built my first big Angular app, and I was always under the impression that during the build process, Angular converts selectors into traditional DOM elements like:

```
<div>
```

But, when I inspect my app with Firebug, I can see that:

```
<app-root>
```

Amongst other tags, still exists.

How is it possible for a browser to understand how to render a custom HTML element like:

```
<app-root>
```

**UPDATE:**

And will an Angular App pass HTML validation?

Comment: Javascript bundles (`main.***.js`, `vendor.***.js`, etc..) that got built along with everything using `ng build`. Upon being served, `index.html` will have those `js` bundles loaded and it loads everything that you've written in your Angular app

Comment: @Chau Tran Yes. But how is a browser able to interpret what <app-root> means? I guess what I am saying, is will an Angular App pass HTML validation?

Comment: When the `index.html` is loaded in the browser, the browser will then start looking into all the embedded `script` tags and will interpret the HTML (in this case, `app-root`) as the `scripts` guide it.

Comment: @Chau Tran So, basically, it is valid to create custom HTML tags, in non Angular projects, as well. For instance, I could create a tag called <foo>Hello World!</foo> and then in my CSS style sheet, do foo{ display: block; }, and the browser would render the text inside a 'block' level element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should pass validation. Creating elements like `<app-root>` is described by the [HTML Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/) as [custom elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-elements). MDN has a good overview of how to create your own [custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements).

At a high level, you need to create a JavaScript class to define the element (perhaps extending an existing element type, like [`<p>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLParagraphElement)):

```
class Foo extends HTMLParagraphElement {...}
```

Then register it in the [Custome Element Registry](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#customelementregistry):

```
customElements.define('foo', Foo, {extends: 'p'});
```

That will create a new `<foo>` element that extends the behavior of the `<p>` element using the definition of the `Foo` class.